# In Swift, why should I create a new variable and set it equal to an enum?

Tags: swift, variables, pointers, struct, enums

*EDITED*
I'm fairly new to swift. I'm trying to understand the following code:

```
struct PersonMovement {
  enum Arms: Int {
    case Bent
    case Straight

    func moreBent() -> Arms {
      return Arms(bentDegree: rawValue - 1) ?? .Straight
    ....
  }
  enum Legs: Int {
    case Bent
    case....
  }
  enum Head: Int {
    ....
  }

  var arms: Arms
  var legs: Legs
  var head: Head
}
```

There is another swift file that uses the variables `arms`, `legs` and `head`. I'm wondering why those separate variables were created in the first place. Why wouldn't the other swift file simply point to the enums `Arms`, `Legs` and `Head` themselves.

Is it because you must ALWAYS create a separate variable with the enum's value if you wish to make use of the enum? Or is it because it is nested and not accessible globally? Again, I'm a newbie here. Sorry for not being clear. Also my second time posting here. Apologies

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your question is, but at the moment your enums are nested types, so you can access them through `PersonMovement.Arms` etc. If you want them to be at global scope, then put them at global scope (move them out of your struct).

Comment: one is the type definition, one is an actual variable. Its like asking why you need to create an instance of a class if you already have that class!?

Comment: oh, so if its nested, is it an internal enum or a private enum?

Comment: @BossGiveMeArrays Well you haven't specified any access modifiers – so it'll be `internal` by default. Nested types don't have anything to do with the actual visibility of the type, as `PersonMovement.Arms` as a nested type is just as visible as `Arms` at the global scope – you just access it at a different scope.

Comment: @BossGiveMeArrays Could you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37240593/edit) with how you're currently attempting to use this code – and what the problem is? I still have no idea what your question is. Doing a Q&A in the comments really isn't how SO works.

Comment: You didn't understand the syntax correctly. `var arms: Arms` - this is an instance of type `Arms`. Now that you have it, you can set it to "bent" or "straight". Can't do it with `Arms` itself.

Comment: Wherever you got this from, sounds like a pretty bad example. It's repeating code, it's unclear what it's trying to attempt. `Arm`, `Leg` and `Head` should each be a `struct`, with `State` being an `enum` that contains `Straight` and `Bent`, then each of the structs could have a `State` property. I would stay away from wherever you got that code from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you are mixing up variables with types.

You define *instances* of variables with the enum *types* of `Arms`, `Legs` and `Head`.

Those instances can then be defined the different enum values, for example:

`arms` can be either `Bent` or `Straight`.